# ¿Como definirle un ID unico a un fragment en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Trato de llamar un fragment para mi Navegation Drawer pero no tiene ID y si yo se lo trato de poner en el archivo XML me marca error

```
FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.aquiMarcaError,new Padre_Scrolling()).commit();
```

Comment: allí debe ir el id del FrameLayout

Answer (score 1):

En tu XML deberías tener algo así, `FrameLayout` que va ser el "contenedor" en donde se va realizar el cambio de los fragments:

....

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

....

En tu archivo java:

```
FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.id_frame,new Padre_Scrolling()).commit();
```

Esto solo funciona si vas agregar un solo Fragment como es tu caso.